# remove characters in string after specific occurrence

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hoping you guys can help me out.

I have a dynamic url and I need some javascript to basically trim the string after the specific occurrence of a character.

**EXAMPLE:**

I have this url

> Assessment/testdir2/TestDIR3/lecture slides 1as.pdf

and I need to remove everything after the `2nd slash` and including the 2nd slash.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very basic JS solution:

```
function removeAfterSlash(word, numberOfElements) {
    var splitWord = word.split('/');
    var newWord = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        if(i != (numberOfElements - 1)) {
            newWord += splitWord[i] + '/';
        } else {
            newWord += splitWord[i];
        }   
    }
    document.write(newWord);
}
removeAfterSlash('Assessment/testdir2/TestDIR3/lecture slides 1as.pdf', 1);
```

Simply split's the word into an array by looking for a `/` and then you can join the elements you need back together. The function takes the word and how many 'segments' you want to join back together.

See it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UptHG/).

Comment: hmm ok yeah I can see that will work, basically though sometimes I will need to remove from the 1st slash sometimes the second and sometimes the 3rd depending on the url that is supplied to the var.

Comment: Updated the answer with a function that can be re-used to do the same thing and takes the word as a parameter and the number of segments you want to put back together.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var url= "Assessment/testdir2/TestDIR3/lecture slides 1as.pdf"
var locs = myString.split('/');
var newUrl = "";
for (var i = 2; i < locs.length; i ++) {
    newUrl += "/" + locs[i];
}
```

This method will then ignore the first two folders and will work regardless of how many other folders you have in the url.